# exit(...): Will it cause parent process to terminate?

Tags: c, exit

If I call exit(1) in the child process, will this action cause parent process to terminate as well? Or simply only child process is terminated by exit(1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit` does not cause the parent to also exit. It causes normal process termination for the current process.

Answer (score 3):

```
man exit
```

This shows

> The exit() function causes normal [current/child] process termination and ***the value of [the exit] status is returned to the parent [process]*** (see wait(2)).
>   ...
>
> After  exit(),  the exit status must be transmitted to the parent process.  There are three cases.  If the parent has set SA_NOCLDWAIT, or has set the SIGCHLD handler to SIG_IGN, the status is discarded.  If the parent was waiting on the child, it is notified of the exit status.
>              In both cases the exiting process dies immediately.  If the parent has not indicated that it is not interested in the exit status, but is not waiting, the exiting process turns into a "zombie" process (which is nothing but a container for the single byte  representing  the  exit
>              status) so that the parent can learn the exit status when it later calls one of the wait(2) functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, the exit() does not terminate the parent process. The exit() function will terminate the current process, and return the exit code to the parent process. So, if you use exit(1), then the exit code 1 will be returned to the parent process.